# How do I create multiple glossary entries for the same definition?

Tags: glossaries

When I have many glossary words that describe the same, how do I neatly put these into the glossary? 
Ideally, something like:

```
\newglossaryentry{digest, hash, hash code} {
name=digest, description={The output of a hash function).}
}
```

producing

**digest**, **hash** or **hash code** The output of a hash function.

is what I'm looking for, and I can't seem to find this anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd define one entry (say, digest) in the usual way and then use `\gls{digest}` in the description field of the alternative entries. See [section 8 of the `glossaries` manual](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf) for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{digest}{name={digest (\textmd{also} hash, hash code)},%
    text=digest,description={The output of a hash function}}

\newglossaryentry{hash}
    {name=hash,description={\emph{See} \gls{digest}}}

\newglossaryentry{hash code}
    {name={hash code},description={\emph{See} \gls{digest}}}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text about \gls{digest}.

Some text about \gls{hash}.

Some text about \gls{hash code}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]